# How can you dynamically bind an images x,y and width to variables using angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I would like to be able to manipulate some images around the screen but can't get it to work properly.

I'v tried using

```
$scope.data[i].style="{'width': '" + $scope.imageScale + "px'}"
```

in the controller, called when imageScale changes, with

```
<div class = "image" ng-repeat="image in data">
    <img ng-src={{image.Filename}} ng-style="image.style">
</div>
```

located in the HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller code isn't going to bind the `style` property like you intend. This is only going to run once, and won't be updated when `$scope.imageScale` changes.

```
$scope.data[i].style="{'width': '" + $scope.imageScale + "px'}"
```

Instead, you can do:

```
<img ng-src={{image.Filename}} ng-style="{'width':$imageScale+'px'}">
```

Or:

```
<img ng-src={{image.Filename}} width="{{$imageScale}}">
```

Or:

```
<img ng-src={{image.Filename}} style="width:{{$imageScale}}px;">
```

Comment: why doesn't this work with "top" and "bottom" css variables?

Comment: Method #1 or #3 should work that way. If you post your code I can give more detail.